# "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" while writing to a file in a loop

Tags: python, file-io

I have to divide a file.txt into more files. Here's the code:

```
a = 0
b = open("sorgente.txt", "r")
c = 5
d = 16 // c
e = 1
f = open("out"+str(e)+".txt", "w")
for line in b:
    a += 1
    f.writelines(line)
    if a == d:
        e += 1
        a = 0
        f.close()
f.close()
```

So , if i run it it gives me this error :

```
todoController\WordlistSplitter.py", line 9, in <module>
    f.writelines(line)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I understood that if you do a for loop the file gets closed so I tried to put the f in the for loop but it doesn't work because instead of getting:

```
out1.txt
 1
 2
 3
 4

out2.txt
 5
 6
 7
 8
```

I get only the last line of the file. What should I do? Are there any way I can recall the open function I defined earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `f.close()` inside the `for` loop, then do not `open` a new file as `f`, hence the error on the next iteration. You should also use `with` to handle files, which saves you needing to explicitly `close` them.

As you want to write four lines at a time to each `out` file, you can do this as follows:

```
file_num = 0
with open("sorgente.txt") as in_file:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(in_file):
        if not line_num % 4:
            file_num += 1
        with open("out{0}.txt".format(file_num), "a") as out_file:
            out_file.writelines(line)
```

Note that I have used variable names to make it a bit clearer what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You close the file but you don't break from for loop.

Answer (score 0):

if a == d you are closing f and then later (in the next iteration) you are trying to write to it which causes the error.
also - why are you closing f twice?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the first `f.close()`:

```
a = 0
b = open("sorgente.txt", "r")
c = 5
d = 16 // c
e = 1
f = open("out"+str(e)+".txt", "w")
for line in b:
    a += 1
    f.writelines(line)
    if a == d:
        e += 1
        a = 0
        # f.close()
f.close()
```