# Open, Write, and Append a Text file

Tags: python

I've run into a bit of a snag with a python script that I was hoping anyone with a fresh pair of eyes and a bit more expertise than myself could spot. I compile, build, and execute the code in Geany if that matters at all. I am getting an error back suggesting a "ValueError I/O operation on closed file".  line 8 specifically the                                                                                             f.write("Appended line %d
r\n  % (i+1))"

```
def main (_):
    """ Function doc """
    
f=  open("AlltheRocks.txt", "a+")

for i in range(2):
    
    f.write("Appended   line    %d\r\n" %   (i+1))
    
    f.close()
    
if __name__==   "__main__":
    main()
```

If any help could be pointed out that would be amazing. I am ultimately trying to see if I can write a single program that opens, writes, and appends multiple text files from potentially different websites as well is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand about the error message. Your program (1) opens a file (2) writes to the file (3) closes the file (4) tries to write to the already closed file again. Solution: only close the file at the end.

Comment: You need to fix your indentation. On multiple levels. Your original code almost certainly had indentation errors, it's not clear you replicated your indentation accurately (you might have, in which case your `main` method is entirely empty and all your code runs in global scope).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" while writing to a file in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637758/valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file-while-writing-to-a-file-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 1):

You have your indentation incorrect.

```py
def main ():
    """ Function doc """
    
    f=  open("AlltheRocks.txt", "a+")

    for i in range(2):
    
        f.write("Appended   line    %d\r\n" %   (i+1))
    
    f.close()
    
if __name__==   "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that answers that problem. At least I hope so.  I believe the two main issues were the indentation like ShadowRanger pointed out were incorrect, and the close statement was also incorrect like Mkrieger1 pointed out was true as well.